# Angular unit test ngOnInit subscription

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am starting out with unit testing in Angular 9 with Jasmine.

I am testing a simple component which implements `ngOnInit`:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private router: Router
        , private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authenticationService.checkIsAuthenticatedObservable()
        .subscribe(
          (isAuthenicated: boolean) => {
            if (isAuthenicated === true) {
              this.router.navigate(['/observation-feed']);
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

I am hitting the error with executing the ngOnInIt lifecycle hook:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at <Jasmine>
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:8140:13)
```

My test spec is setup like this:

```
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let router: Router;
  let mockAuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['checkIsAuthenticatedObservable']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          // { path: 'login', component: DummyLoginLayoutComponent },
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: mockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    mockAuthenticationService.checkIsAuthenticatedObservable.and.returnValue(of(false));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // component.ngOnInit();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have attempted various combinations of setting up the mock object, and calling `fixture.detectChanges();` and `component.ngOnInit();` at different points in the intialization.  None of what I have tried has worked.  What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are calling `fixture.detectChanges` in the `beforeEach` section, Angular runs lifecycle hooks and `ngOnInit` is called. This is why you're getting error - you are mocking `checkIsAuthenticatedObservable` in the test, after the first `fixture.detectChanges`.
Move your mock to the `beforeEach` section, before `fixture.detectChanges` and it will work correctly.
Also, with Angular 9, you should use `TestBed.inject` instead of `TestBed.get` which is now deprecated.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockAuthenticationService.checkIsAuthenticatedObservable.and.returnValue(of(false));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Glad, I could help :)